# timeoutSecs for RequestQueue ignoring user config?

Tags: crawlee

I use RequestQueue like so:

```
    const requestQueue = await RequestQueue.open();
    requestQueue.timeoutSecs = 60;
    await requestQueue.addRequest(...);
```

but when running scraper I still see the default timeout:

```
WARN  CheerioCrawler: Reclaiming failed request back to the list or queue. request timed out after 30 seconds.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not specify higher level timeout in crawler settings then its a bug, please add issue at github for https://crawlee.dev/api/core/class/RequestQueue#timeoutSecs